# Finite directed graph and even degree

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory

I have a problem solving this question :

I need to prove that if i have a finite not directed graph that every vertex in him have an even degree, i can direct all of it edges in a way that the in degree of every vertex equals to its out degree.

I have tried to solve it by induction and didn't really succeded.

thank you.

Comment: Just drawing euler path would be helpful because all vertices have even degree

Comment: @Merdanov how can i do that ?

Comment: You have the euler path that covers all edges, and it's starting point and ending point coincide. So start from starting point to direct the edges along the euler path, you've done.

Answer (score 1):

If each vertex of graph $G$ has an even degree, then each connected component of $G$ [is Eulerian graph](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerianGraph.html), i. e. each component has a cycle that includes all edges of this component. Then you can direct each edge in order of traversing an Eulerian cycle of corresponding connected component.